# IE shows mirrored image as before/after content

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Only IE shows the img.png image mirrored. Why? How do I cope with it without creating a mirrored image specifically to IE?

```css
body {
    direction: rtl;
}
li:before {
  content: url(/img/img.png);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Txza7/2/

Comment: Can you make a demo? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Well, I added dir:ltr ruler to li:before and it works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @SRachamim don't forget you can add your own answer and accept it in 48hrs. It means you can close off your question and get some upvotes if someone has the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Problem solved: I had to set direction: ltr ruler to li:before in order to get it right.

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
}
li:before {
  content: url(/img/img.png);
  direction: ltr;
}
```